# How can I make this query take multiple columns?

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have this query:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z, "Select * Where B contains 'name")
```

and I want to make where it takes B, take multiple columns, such as it looks in A, B, C.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, you want to search more than just column B for 'name'? Do you also want to see if it is in column D, H, Z, etc?

If so:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z,"SELECT * WHERE (A CONTAINS 'name' OR B CONTAINS 'name' OR C CONTAINS 'name')")
```

add `OR column CONTAINS 'name'` for each column you want to check.

For example,

[image: this screenshot]

shows that it checks column A, B, and C for 'name', but not column D.

Answer (score 0):

the shorter version is like this:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z, "where A contains 'name' 
                       or B contains 'name' 
                       or C contains 'name')", 0)
```

also if your dataset is really huge you may want to use `FILTER` instead of query:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z, REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!A:A, "name")+
                    REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!B:B, "name")+
                    REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!C:C, "name"))
```

or also like:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*name*", Sheet1!A:A))+
                    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*name*", Sheet1!B:B))+
                    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*name*", Sheet1!C:C)))
```